# What is contained in the Dungeon Defenders PlayStation Plus Free DLC?

Tags: psn, dungeon-defenders, playstation-plus

On the [PlayStation Blog's PS Store update for the Dungeon Defenders launch](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/10/18/playstation-store-update-209/), it specifically cited that, in addition to releasing Dungeon Defenders itself, also available for download would be:

> "Dungeon Defenders PlayStation Plus Exclusive DLC (Free & Exclusive to
>   PlayStation Plus members )"

But I could not find any information about what this DLC actually IS.  Does anyone know what this content is?  There is nothing specified on the page except for that quote, and I was unable to find specific details of this DLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [recent blog post](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/10/19/prepare-for-glory-dungeon-defenders-is-available-now-on-psn/) clarifies this, the exclusive DLC consists of four familiars, three of which have slightly elevated stats for their level, and the fourth is a monkey who shoots enemies with his banana-guns... Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

The free add-on for PS Plus is pets that help attack enemies.

Comment: Hey Fakehater, welcome to the site! Since a lot of this answer wasn't, well, related to answering the question but seemed to be instead a lot of fake hate towards the game, I removed several paragraphs from your answer. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: was warning people of its issues but to each there own I own the game and know of it's trophy sinc issues
more about it here http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/general-ps3-discussion/4436-dungeon-defenders-broken.html